# How to select default graphics adapter?

Tags: windows, windows-10, direct3d, direct3d11

My code calls `D3D11CreateDevice` like that:

```
HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice( nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr,
    flags, levels.data(), levelsCount, D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &g_device, &g_featureLevel, &g_context );
```

The documentation says about the first argument “Pass NULL to use the default adapter”, so far so good.

Recently I received a bug report from a user who has 3 adapters (2 discrete ones, and one integrated in the CPU), with a very reasonable complain they can’t select which of them is used by my software.

How does Windows selects which of them is the default, and how can user affect that setting?

Comment: I believe it's the adapter associated with the Primary Windows desktop (or the non-"secondary" display and adapter in mirroring scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

The default device is typically controlled by settings from the user.

For "Hybrid graphics" scenarios typically on a laptop, the decision is up to the hardware vendor's software to pick the 'default' which changes from app to app. To influence this, you can export special variables from your program but this only provides the defaults as the hardware vendor settings can override it.

```
// Indicates to hybrid graphics systems to prefer the discrete part by default
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
    __declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1;
}
```

With Windows 10 (15063) or later you can use `IDXGIFactory6::EnumAdapterByGpuPreference` to enumerate by `DXGI_GPU_PREFERENCE_HIGH_PERFORMANCE` or `DXGI_GPU_PREFERENCE_MINIMUM_POWER` rather than rely on the 'default' logic.

Comment: I also noted that the new **DXTK for DX12 GameDR** templates for Win11 desktop had removed the default variable exports from _main.cpp_ and were indeed enumerating adapters using `IDXGIFactory6::EnumAdapterByGpuPreference` in _DeviceResources.cpp_. I develop on a laptop and therefore also depend on a hybrid graphics scenario. Thanks for this explanation.

Comment: The DirectX 12 case is a little bit more complicated because it is possible to have multiple adapters in the system, but not all of them support DX12. Therefore, my [directx-vs-template](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) for DirectX 12 never uses the 'default' and always enumerates.